# Bootstrap 3 - append button to text field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, input

Using Bootstrap 3 (latest) code below ...

```
<form>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-8">
  <label class="control-label">Text Field Label</label>
  <div class="input-group">
   <input name="f1" value="" class="form-control" type="text" size="20" maxlength="100" placeholder="Text Field">
   <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="b1" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Button Label</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
 <!-- Other elements to go here -->
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The above code renders as follows (screen shot) on all browsers I have tested:

[image]

But no matter what combination I try, if the button has more than 2 or 3 characters in it, the button wraps the text and appears too large (higher than the text input field) -- how can this be fixed to allow the button to contain more text WITHOUT appearing larger (in height) than the text input field?

Please Note - I do NOT want to use "form-inline" as I need to have other elements in the row -- I only included the column that contains the relevant form elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oq4fk89o/1) , your code looks ok.

```
Maybe you missed load Jquery 1.11.x ?
```

Load order:

- bootstrap.min.css
- jquery.min.js  ( 1.11 or + )
- bootstrap.min.js

As a last option, "Inspect" the button and check if other classes are being applied.

Comment: - Inspected element - BINGO -- found a .btn class in another style sheet that had .btn {white-space: normal !important;} -- which of course was overriding the bootstraps .btn white-space:no-wrap directive -- Thanks Mate!!

Comment: Great! It's a particular and common case.. you could mark this answer as correct or delete your question.